# What are functors, and why do we need them?

Tags: functor, factor-lang

I don't understand Factor's [functors](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/vocab-functors.html). I guess it would help to first understand what  a "functor" is.

Google says:

> a function; an operator.

In Factor, all functions (words) are operators, and are first-class. (In fact, I can't think of much in Factor that *isn't* first class). This definition isn't so helpful.

Wikipedia says:

> Functor may refer to:
>
> - ...
> - **In computer programming:**
>
>   - **function object** used to pass function pointers along with its state
>   - ...
>   - In Haskell a Functor describes **a generalisation of functions that perform mapping operations**

The page for "function object" says:

> an object to be invoked or called as if it were an ordinary function, usually with the same syntax (a function parameter that can also be a function).

So a functor is a first-class function? This is nothing special, and anyways words and quotations and stuff are already first-class in Factor.

Factor Functors have weird syntax that reminds me of generics or something.

[resource:unmaintained/models/combinators/templates/templates.factor](https://github.com/factor/factor/blob/c51f518911c46b6ff93a33296cd683781ed52b2a/unmaintained/models/combinators/templates/templates.factor):

```
FROM: models.combinators => <collection> #1 ;
FUNCTOR: fmaps ( W -- )
W IS ${W}
w-n      DEFINES ${W}-n
w-2      DEFINES 2${W}
w-3      DEFINES 3${W}
w-4      DEFINES 4${W}
w-n*     DEFINES ${W}-n*
w-2*     DEFINES 2${W}*
w-3*     DEFINES 3${W}*
w-4*     DEFINES 4${W}*
WHERE
MACRO: w-n ( int -- quot ) dup '[ [ _ narray <collection> ] dip [ _ firstn ] prepend W ] ;
: w-2 ( a b quot -- mapped ) 2 w-n ; inline
: w-3 ( a b c quot -- mapped ) 3 w-n ; inline
: w-4 ( a b c d quot -- mapped ) 4 w-n ; inline
MACRO: w-n* ( int -- quot ) dup '[ [ _ narray <collection> #1 ] dip [ _ firstn ] prepend W ] ;
: w-2* ( a b quot -- mapped ) 2 w-n* ; inline
: w-3* ( a b c quot -- mapped ) 3 w-n* ; inline
: w-4* ( a b c d quot -- mapped ) 4 w-n* ; inline
;FUNCTOR
```

The documentation is extremely sparse on these. What are they? When should I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of functors as that ['They're named "functors" to annoy category theory fanboys and language purists.'](http://factor-language.blogspot.se/2009/05/unboxed-tuple-arrays-in-factor.html) :)

Their use is mainly to generate boilerplate or template code. Just like C++ templates are an optimization feature because generic dispatch can be slow, so are Factor functors.

Example here:

```
USING: functors io lexer namespaces ;
IN: examples.functors

FUNCTOR: define-table ( NAME -- )

name-datasource DEFINES-CLASS ${NAME}-datasource

clear-name DEFINES clear-${NAME}
init-name DEFINES init-${NAME}

WHERE

SINGLETON: name-datasource

: clear-name ( -- ) "clear table code here" print ;

: init-name ( -- ) "init table code here" print ;

name-datasource [ "hello-hello" ] initialize

;FUNCTOR

SYNTAX: SQL-TABLE: scan-token define-table ;
```

You can now write `SQL-TABLE: person` and Factor will create the words `clear-person`, `init-person` and `person-datasource` for you.

When to use them? I think never unless you have performance problems that warrants their use. They are very bad for [grepability](https://product.reverb.com/2013/03/29/rails-fails-dont-sacrifice-grepability-for-terseness/).